# UI changing after sharing app via shareit or similar apps like shareit

Tags: android, android-layout

When the apk file is installed, the UI looks same as it was designed in android studio but when the app is shared using Shareit (or any other sharing application), the UI changes the place. Also, the app starts lagging too much even it is less than 7mb.

[This is the actual design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsRjP.jpg)
[This is the UI after sharing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrOIt.jpg)

Both screenshots are of 5.5 inch display mobiles.

For the screen compatibility i used constraint layout and i added the needed attributes to the buttons and image-view so that they can grow or shrink according to the screen size.

Comment: Sharit does not change your apk, but your UI is not mobile screen friendly, whenever it goes to another device maybe they have different screens sizes and resolution, Check your app UI in all screen sizes first.

Comment: Have not seen anything like this in my life.. this is not problem of share it. Your app layout isn't compatible with all the screens.